# Save files names in numpy file (.npy)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I  have a folder that has some pickles files, I would like to save the file names in a numpy file (file .np)
I am able to save file names in text file (`file1.txt`) as the following:

```
A23H.Pickel
H3DH.Pickle
H2T4.pickle
...
```

However, I am not able to save them in `file.npy` or convert that txt file to numpy file `file2.npy`. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `np.save('filename.npy',your_numpy_array)`

Comment: I want to save the dat inside txt in npy file and evry A23H.Pickel
 should be str numpy how can i do that